# VBA Project (Module + Form) work when saved to directly to workbook, but break when saved to Personal workbook

Tags: excel, vba, userform

My macro looks at a previous day report and gives a true if the ID in column C is found in it.

When the code and user form are saved to today's report (or whatever day I am running) it works like a charm. When I transfer the module and form to my personal workbook, it breaks.

I use a placeholder for the formula that is replaced with the data entry from the form.

Both columns are created in columns A and B, data validation and formatting look good. But from A2 down it's blank instead of having the formula that looks at the previous report.

```
Sub Macro_Test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create columns Previous Day and Review Needed
Columns("A:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Previous Report" 'True or False
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Review Needed" 'True or False
Range("A1:B1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Data Validation Review Needed
Range("B2:B5000").Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="TRUE,FALSE"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

'Formula for previous day
 UserForm.Show

Range("P1:Q1").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[2],'https://website/Reports/[Report - 2024.01.01.xlsx]Sheet1'!C3,1,FALSE))=TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)"
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A5000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A5000").Select

Range("A1:A5000").Replace What:="2024.01.01", Replacement:=Range("Q1") & "." & Range("O1") & "." & Range("P1")

'Returns to A1 and Freeze Row 1
Columns("O:Q").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Range("A1:L1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter

Range("A1").Select
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0

'Delete formula if row is empty
Dim LastRowColC As Long, LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastRowColC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow > LastRowColC Then
  Rows(LastRowColC + 1 & ":" & LastRow).Clear
End If

Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


'Submit button from UserForm
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheet1.Activate

Range("P1").Value = TextBox1.Value

Range("Q1").Value = TextBox2.Value

Range("R1").Value = TextBox3.Value


Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: A very useful resource is learning [how to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify which file / sheet is to be active.

Comment: Have you tried qualifying your objects so the program knows which sheet you are referring to?

Comment: Of course! I was missing it for the UserForm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The UserForm was data entrying to the Personal Workbook. The solution was referring back to my active sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ThisWS As Worksheet

Set ThisWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Range("P1").Value = TextBox1.Value

Range("Q1").Value = TextBox2.Value

Range("R1").Value = TextBox3.Value


Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the point of `ThisWS` if you never use it? In other words, consider putting `ThisWS.` in front of each `Range` call.

Comment: I apologize. ThisWS is used in a different part of the code. I did not paste the code in it's entirety to simplify. Thank you for the tip of having it just in front of Range.